# Iterate through multiple web pages in JS with sleep in between

Tags: javascript

I was checking some simple solutions for showing multiple web pages for some dashboard and currently fighting with simple HTML page with javascript inside to achieve what I want to see there.

```
var urls = new Array();
urls[0] = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
urls[1] = "https://www.google.com"

var arrayLength = urls.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  window.location.assign(urls[i]);
  sleep(3000);
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Currently this page opens only first page (after some time) and looks like it doesn't do iteration trough other pages. Maybe you could help me to make it work? I want to rotate those pages forever on screen (will add some infinite while loop after making this part working).

Comment: Are you trying to send the browser to each page every few seconds, infinitely?

Comment: Basically yes, but in real life it will happen most probably every 60 seconds and doing iteration between 9 or less pages. Will think about some cache cleaning and browser restarts little bit later. I found some solution with iframes, but looks like some of the pages I want to display is blocked by using iframes.

Answer (score 2):

> Currently this page opens only first page (after some time) and looks
>   like it doesn't do iteration trough other pages.

Once you change your window.location, and go to the first url from the array, you are losing all of your JS code (as it is not present in just opened url any more).

Comment: Ok, missed that part in my mind.. Is there any way how to properly achieve this?

Comment: If the pages you want to load have 'X-Frame-Options' set to 'sameorigin' you cannot load them in iframe as you already found out by yourself. If you do not insist on embedding them, you can use automation tools (as AutoIt ) to redirect your browser to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by installing a [chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/run-javascript/lmilalhkkdhfieeienjbiicclobibjao) (which will not lose your JS after `window.location` change).
The plugin will run the added JS at `DOMContentLoaded` (no need to attach any event listener).

I needed also to do this, check things on the page, store some information and move on to the next page. I know, this can be done with Python and other stuff but by doing this it can be done on the FE side also.

I used the `localStorage` to store my information.

I pasted this into the browser console to prepare all the stuff and clean the `localStorage`:

```
// clear the localStorage
localStorage.clear();

// set an array that will keep all our pages to iterate into the localStorage
localStorage.setItem(
  "pages",
  JSON.stringify([
    "https://my-page-1.html",
    "https://my-page-2.html",
    "https://my-page-3.html",
    "https://my-page-4.html",
  ])
);

// set an array that will keep our findings
localStorage.setItem("resultArray", JSON.stringify([]));

// move to the first page of the iteration
window.location.href = "https://my-page-1.html";
```

After doing this, I opened the plugin interface and added the following code:

```
(function check() {
  // array saved into the localStorage that contains all the pages to iterate
  const pagesArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pages"));

  // array to store your stuff
  const resultArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("resultArray"));

  // whatever you want to check on that page
  const myFancyCondition = true;

  if (myFancyCondition) {
    // push any data to the array so that you can check it later
    resultArray.push({
      page: pagesArray[0],
      message: "I found what I was looking for!",
    });
  }

  //remove the current page from the array
  pagesArray.shift();

  //reset the array value after the first page was already checked
  localStorage.setItem("pages", JSON.stringify(pagesArray));

  //store the array data
  localStorage.setItem("resultArray", JSON.stringify(resultArray));

  // quit if the iteration is over and there are no more pages to check
  if(!pagesArray.length) return;

  //go to the next page
  window.location.href = pagesArray[0];
})();
```

Then, to check the results you just need to read the data from the `localStorage` like:

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('resultArray'))`

I hope this helps :)!